# How to handle the response coming as array of objects in reactive forms in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

i am getting an array of objects as a response and assigning it to a multiselect (ng-select) which has a formControlName 'custom'. The response which i get looks like this

```
this.taskList = [
    { 'clientTaskId' : '1', 'taskName': 'hardware setup', billableRate: '500', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '2', 'taskName': 'software installation', billableRate: '250', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '3', 'taskName': 'environment setup', billableRate: '700', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '4', 'taskName': 'cafeteria setup', billableRate: '1200', customRate: ''},
    ];
```

here is my formGroup

```
 clientForm = this.fb.group([
 custom: ['']
 ])
```

now whatever object I select. I populate it in a table, where one column of the table is editable. Now I edit the data in the editable column of the table and when i hit the save button I should get the response with edited data.

I have populated the data using the formControl name.

here is my code :

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormBuilder,Validators, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgSelectModule, NgOption} from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(clientForm.value)">
      <ng-select 
        placeholder="Select custom rates"
        [items]="taskList"
        [multiple]="true"
        bindLabel="taskName"
        [addTag]="true"
        [closeOnSelect]="false"
        clearAllText="Clear"
        formControlName = "custom"
        >
      </ng-select>

      <br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
          <th scope="col">Task Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Custom Rate</th>
            <th scope="col">Standard Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let task of clientForm.controls['custom'].value">
            <td>{{ task.taskName }}</td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="" >
            </td> 
            <td>{{ task.billableRate}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  taskList : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskList = [
    { 'clientTaskId' : '1', 'taskName': 'hardware setup', billableRate: '500', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '2', 'taskName': 'software installation', billableRate: '250', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '3', 'taskName': 'environment setup', billableRate: '700', customRate: ''},
    { 'clientTaskId' : '4', 'taskName': 'cafeteria setup', billableRate: '1200', customRate: ''},
    ];
  }

  submit(formValue){
    console.log(formValue)
  }
  clientForm = this.fb.group({
    custom : ['']
  })
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ) {  }

}
```

here is the demo : 
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-predefined-template-mct5vw)

I am a beginner to angular-reactive-forms and I am bit confused about how to use formArray and formGroup. and how to deal with the response of array of objects.

Hope you understand my question, if you need any clarity please comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to patch response as array??

Comment: I tried assigning the custom as formArray , but it gave a different result. the options which i select should act as a two way binding in the table. but I dont know how to do that in reactive forms. As I have mentioned I am new to reactive forms and bit confused how to handle such scenario

Comment: @Deepakparamesh to use `array` as a form value, there is a more efficient way, please clarify your needs, so we can help.

Comment: @HamidAsghari yea exactly, I want to have the custom as an array. but when i assign it as a formArray, I am not able to populate the values already present in the custom. I referenced these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968619/angular-2-how-to-use-array-of-objects-for-controls-in-reactive-forms    https://ashish173.github.io/ng2-forms/trip/create. which is similar to my needs.

Comment: @Deepakparamesh what do you mean by `not able to populate the values already present in the custom`?

Comment: @HamidAsghari i.e I am not able to display the "taskName," "standard rate " present in the response in the table. I iterate the response with <*ngFor let task of clentForm.controls.custom ; i = index >. I assign the formControlName of the inputValue as customRate. but cannot display the previous value {{ task.taskName }}

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-predefined-template-k8qjo5)

Access form Array element as :

```
{{clientForm.controls.customer.controls[i].controls.billableRate.value}}
```

Code HTML & TS:

```
import { Component, NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule, NgOption } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="clientForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(clientForm.value)">

      <table class="table" formArrayName="customer">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
          <th scope="col">Task Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Custom Rate</th>
            <th scope="col">Standard Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let task of clientForm.controls['customer'].controls; let i= index" [formGroupName]="i" >
            <td>{{clientForm.controls.customer.controls[i].controls.taskName.value}}</td>
            <td>
              <input formControlName="customRate" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="" >
            </td> 
            <td>{{clientForm.controls.customer.controls[i].controls.billableRate.value}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>

    <div>{{clientForm.value |json}}</div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  customer: FormArray;
  clientForm: FormGroup;
  taskList: Array<any> = [
    { clientTaskId: '1', taskName: 'hardware setup', billableRate: '500', customRate: '' },
    { clientTaskId: '2', taskName: 'software installation', billableRate: '250', customRate: '' },
    { clientTaskId: '3', taskName: 'environment setup', billableRate: '700', customRate: '' },
    { clientTaskId: '4', taskName: 'cafeteria setup', billableRate: '1200', customRate: '' },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();

    this.customer = this.getData();

    while (this.getData().length) {
      this.customer.removeAt(0)
    }

    for (let d of this.taskList) {
      this.addMore(d);
    }
  }

  getData() {
    return this.clientForm.get('customer') as FormArray;
  }

  addMore(d) {
    this.getData().push(this.buildCusforms(d));
  }

  buildCusforms(data) {
    if (!data) {
      data = {
        clientTaskId: null,
        taskName: null,
        billableRate: null,
        customRate: null
      }
    }
    return this.fb.group({
      clientTaskId: data.clientTaskId,
      taskName: data.taskName,
      billableRate: data.billableRate,
      customRate: data.customRate
    });
  }


  createForm() {
    this.clientForm = this.fb.group({
      customer: this.fb.array([this.buildCusforms({
        clientTaskId: null,
        taskName: null,
        billableRate: null,
        customRate: null
      })])
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: For the `*ngFor` you just need to write `customer.controls`
Same inside the ngFor, you can replace the `clientForm.controls.customer.controls[i]` for just `task`