# Angular Reactive form Validation for dynamic forms inside *ngFor

Tags: node.js, angular, forms, validation, ngfor

I am new to angular when I was trying to put the form validation to the text field form was present inside `*ngFor` loop, So validation is working but it shows to every field but I want validation the particular field only , so please help me How to put the validation to the particular form field.

```
**HTML** 

    <div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="display: block; ">

              <form [formGroup]="commentForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="comment_Submit(post.user_id, post.post_id,
                commentForm)">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment{{i}}" formControlName="comment" id="comment"
                    placeholder="Enter comments" cols="40" rows="5" spellcheck="true"
                    style="width:100%; height: auto; border: 1px solid #ada5a5; border-radius: 4px; outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word; "
                    [ngClass]="{'form-control': true,
                  'is-invalid': !f.comment.valid,
                  'is-valid':f.comment.valid}">
                  <div *ngIf="f.comment.errors?.minlength && f.comment.touched" class="text-danger">Comment
                    should be at
                    least 2 characters.</div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="!commentForm.valid">Comment</button>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

**TypeScript**
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

get f() { return this.commentForm.controls; }

constructor(private userService: UserService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private alerts: AlertsService) {
   this.commentFormValidation();

  }

commentForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {   }

    commentFormValidation() {
     this.commentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      comment: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
    });
  }
```

Comment: create stackblitz and share to help you on this. And You can solve such case using FormArray

Comment: to check if is valid "comment, you must use: commentForm.controls.coment.valid, anyway, Angular add class for you when is invalid a field, see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i am looking for the iteration of form validation inside *ngFor loop

Comment: What you want is `FormArray`. That just looks kinda weird. You would want to put the `posts` array **inside** the formgroup, instead of trying to iterate your array and stick a form for each.

Comment: Check my answer here, it should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975138/6294072

Comment: I can't put post array in the form because , i am using the form for writing comment for my posts , for every post there is a comment box below the post description , for the comment box i am putting the validation, validation working correctly but when it got error it shows for every comment field 
So i need solution for that .Help me in this using  i="index" .

Answer (score 0):

Your `posts` all share the one and same form. If you have `n` amount of `posts`, you need `n` amount of forms. We can achieve this by creating an array (just a JS array) of formgroups, the same length that your `posts` array is...

```ts
formsArr = [];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.posts.forEach((x) => {
    this.formsArr.push(this.fb.group({
      comment: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])
    }))
  })
}
```

Then in your template you iterate `formsArr`. You probably need access to some stuff in your `posts` array... so we add the index in iteration, therefore you can access the specific `post` with `posts[i]`. Also remove `method="post"` from your form:

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of formsArr; let i = index">
  <form [formGroup]="a" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(a.value, posts[i].user_id)">
    <input formControlName="comment" />
    <small *ngIf="a.hasError('minlength', 'comment') && a.get('comment').touched">
      Needs to be 2 letters
    </small>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!a.valid">Comment</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xea4ij?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Sir once check my TypeScript code

My github link 

https://github.com/sivasankarchimata/Angular-Node.js-MySQL-social-networking-site-/tree/master/git

Comment: getting error like this when i am using this.posts array from database ,


ProfileComponent.html:54 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at PostsComponent.push../src/app/user/posts/posts.component.ts.PostsComponent.ngOnInit (posts.component.ts:70)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9250)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)

Comment: well apparently `this.posts` is `undefined`. You need to do the iteration inside the subscribe callback, as a http-request is asynchronous: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you are having issues with your code, please fork my stackblitz and reproduce the issue. The above is a demo, just showing how you should do it. If your posts is coming in asynchronously, you need to execute the above code **when** posts actually have value.

Comment: https://github.com/sivasankarchimata/Angular-Node.js-MySQL-social-networking-site-/tree/master/git

this is my github link for the source files

Comment: So like I guessed, getting posts is asynchronous. Iterate the post *when you have data* I've told you many times and even linked you a question on how asynxhronozity works ;)