# Angular Form Array declaration in formcontrol

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form in my project which contains multiple formcontrols. But one of them named "shopIds" have to be array. Now I want to pass empty array through shopIds. How can I do that? Here I am adding my codes:

Ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
  }

  formInit = () => {
    this.couponForm = new FormGroup({
      couponCode: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      quantity: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      quantityPerUser: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      startDate: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      endDate: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      shopIds: new FormControl([]),
      minimumAmount: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      reductionPercent: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      reductionAmount: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      priority: new FormControl(1),
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968619/angular-2-how-to-use-array-of-objects-for-controls-in-reactive-forms

Comment: Instead of `shopIds: new FormControl([]),` use `shopIds: new FormArray([]),`

Comment: Full working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yfzkr8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shopIds: new FormArray([])`,

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray